# Marginal distribution of a function of order statistics

Tags: self-study, density-function, joint-distribution, order-statistics, marginal-distribution

From the joint distribution of any two order statistics, say $Y_j$ and $Y_k$, $j<k$ I would like to derive the distribution of $Z=F(Y_k)-F(Y_j)$.

The initial pdf is:

$$f_{Y_j,Y_k} (y_j,y_k) =\frac{n!}{(j-1)!(k-1-j)!(n-k)!} \times [F(Y_j)]^{j-1} [F(y_k)-F(y_j)]^{k-1-j} \times[1-F(y_k)]^{n-k} f(y_j) f(y_k)$$

Now I make the substitutions $Z=F(Y_k)-F(Y_j)$ and $ Y=F(Y_j)$ and the strategy is to get joint distribution of $Z$ and $Y$ and inegrate out $y$ to get the marginal distribution of $Z$.

Now the joint distribution is

$$f_{Z,Y} (z,y)=\frac{n!}{(j-1)!(k-1-j)!(n-k)!} z^{k-1-j} y^{j-1}(1-z-y)^{n-k} $$

and unless I am mistaken the support is $\{0<z,y<1 \}$, yes? If that is the case, now I need to evaluate the integral

$$f_Z (z)=\int_{0}^{1}  \frac{n!}{(j-1)!(k-1-j)!(n-k)!} z^{k-1-j} y^{j-1}(1-z-y)^{n-k}dy$$

This is the part where I would appreciate some help. The integral looks like a beta pdf but that $z$ in the integrand confuses me. Are there any tricks here?

Thank you.

Comment: Necessarily $0\le z+y\le 1$.  The integral is then easily converted into a Beta value.

Comment: @whuber Certainly yes. But which subsitution are you suggesting?

Comment: There are two obvious substitutions: $y\to y/(1-z)$ and $y\to 1-y/(1-z)$, because both of them immediately make the integrand into a Beta integrand and change the range of integration to the interval $[0,1]$.

Comment: Oh thank you. The original range of integration should have been $0$ to $1-z$ then?

Comment: Please see my first comment.  Also, consider what $(1-z-y)^{n-k}$ would equal if $y\gt 1-z$: it could give you a negative integrand, which wouldn't be a valid probability density.

Comment: I have. But isn't that what it implies? We know then that $0<y<1-z$. I apologise if I am being slow.

Comment: Remember where these conditions come from: $y$ is the quantile of order statistic $j$ and $y+z$ is the quantile of order statistic $k$ with $k\gt j$. Thus $y$, being a quantile, cannot be less than $0$; $y+z$, also being a quantile, cannot exceed $1$; and $z\ge 0$. Therefore $y$ must be integrated from $0$ to $1-z$ under the assumption $0\le z\le 1$. When you are integrating over $y$, $z$ is a constant--and this gets us back to your question. What is confusing about the presence of a constant in an integrand?

Comment: @whuber Nothing after your clarifications.I appreciate your help, thank you very much.